# How difficult is it to customise NopCommerce?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

My customer wants an e-commerce site. I'm a .NET dev so NopCommerce seems like a good place to start but I haven't used MVC or NopCommerce before. I'm keen to learn about them but first I need to quote this job quickly.

The problem is his requirements are quite different to a standard shop site. This is difficult to explain without broadcasting his business idea. A customer will go to the site and chose a "container". This may be a small, medium or large container. The small container costs $20, the medium costs $30 etc.

Each container entitles the customer to purchase a certain number of products. For example the small contain can hold 10 points worth of products. Once the customer has chosen their container, they need to chose products to go in the container. They may add some socks, these are 1 point. Then they may add a shirt, this is 3 point. And so on until they are up to 10 points.

Also, once a container is ordered and filled, the customer needs to be able to enable repeated delivery of this container (say every week) with recurring billing.

I hope this question isn't considered too vague but I'm just in the initial quoting stage of the project it would really help me if I had some idea of how difficult this may be. I'm an experience dev but have used WebForms and WinForms for most previous jobs and I've just had a year off so I'm a little out of touch. Once I've spent some time learning more about MVC and NopCommerce will this be reasonably easy or not? Should I be using NopCommerce or would I be better off building this from scratch or using another framework?

Comment: Not familiar with NopCommerce, so I dont know if it supports a subscription model but you could have a service which automatically submits new orders weekly.  I dont think you'll have a problem with MVC considering your background.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and encouragement Mark :)

Comment: I just checked and there is the concept of reccurring orders with NopCommerce, see - http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/3536/recurring-product.aspx

Comment: Thanks again Mark. I'm going with NopCommerce.

Comment: I have previously been able to customize NopCommerce heavily and it has always been really a good idea. I definitely do not recommend you to start from scratch because in the end you will be redoing some if the amazing code that NopCommerce has. 

I wrote a blog post about how NopCommerce can be used as a platform: http://carlosmartinezt.com/2013/11/nopcommerce-as-a-platform-part-1/ It should give you an idea of the amount of time that you can save if you do this kind of project with Nopcommerce. 

I recommend you to price your specific project as a custom build because you will be creating yo

Answer (score 1):

To do modifications you need know:
- c# (very easy)
- asp net mvc (if you know mvc archtecture, will be easy too)
- change/create controllers and views to do what you want (easy, buy take time)
- create/change plugins/widget (it´t easy, because nop has a lot of interfaces that "teaches" how create you code (IPlugin))

I work with nopCommerce a long time and I liked.